# why are my static files not getting detected in django?

Tags: django

I want to add a static file to my django project app.

My app is named "core"

Hence inside the app where I need the static file (called main.css) , I made a directory named static/core/main.css

So after that my directory looks like this

```
core
....
-static
|_core
  |_main.css
.........
```

And in the settings.py file , I wrote this

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And in the html file where I want the static css I wrote this

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %} Welcome | Ecommerce {% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/main.css' %}">
```

This HTML file is located in a global project level template folder where I dump the templates from all the apps in the project .

But my static file is not getting loaded for some reason

Comment: Have you added url_patterns https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#static? Debug=true or false?

Answer (score 0):

May be because you didn't specify the file?

I guess you should change it from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '' %}">
```

To

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/main.css' %}">
```

Try to add

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

into your Django settings

Comment: Sorry . I had mentioned the file name in my original code but I did not copy paste it correctly . <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/main.css' %}"> <-- this is what i have in my code too. It is still not working

Comment: Does Django shows any errors? Are you sure that BASE_DIR found correctly in your project? Are static files loaded on other pages? Did you try to restart the server?

Comment: You can try to manually go to the address /static/core/main.css? Is the server responding with a 404 error?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/main.css' %}"> <-- When I wrote this line in pycharm , I am getting a warning "Unresolved template reference ''core/main.css'' "

Comment: Probably you need to add your static directory to STATICFILES_DIRS setting as Nguyễn Vũ Thiên mentioned. See more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs

Answer (score -1):

In Your settings.py file add this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    ]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

after that open the terminal in your root directory and run the following command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

you can also refer to the django documentation where they have explained about staticfiles in django *https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/*